# O que a função "argumentos" escrita em PHP faz?

Tags: php, string

[Código completo](https://github.com/googleinurl/INURLMAIL/blob/master/inurlmail.php)

```
function argumentos($argv, $campo) {
        $_ARG = array();
        foreach ($argv as $arg) {
            if (ereg('--[a-zA-Z0-9]*=.*', $arg)) {
                $str = split("=", $arg);
                $arg = '';
                $key = ereg_replace("--", '', $str[0]);
                for ($i = 1; $i < count($str); $i++) {
                    $arg .= $str[$i];
                }
                $_ARG[$key] = $arg;
            } elseif (ereg('-[a-zA-Z0-9]', $arg)) {
                $arg = ereg_replace("-", '', $arg);
                $_ARG[$arg] = 'true';
            }
        }
        return $_ARG[$campo];
    }
```

Qual a funcionalidade desta função?

Comment: Faça um tour para entender o fucionamento do site stackoverflow: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ela separa e valida argumentos vindos, provavelmente de linha de comando, e retorna um deles especificamente. Ao que parece os argumentos existem em duas forma: pares de chave e valor separados por um `=` após um `--`; e nomes simples iniciados por `-` que só precisam ter existência.